# Are any kinds of behavior proved to correlate with testosterone levels?

Tags: behavior, testosterone, correlation

Are any kinds of behavior proved to correlate with testosterone levels?
Any studies done on this? Any indications of such correlations?

Comment: I really need to find a link to that interview, - a transgender woman who became a man and got high levels of testosterone injections. She described dramatic changes in her thoughts of women- a lot more aggressive sexual thoughts.  Low levels of testosterone in men have negative effects on cognition - depressed moods, irritability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "There was a significantly **higher level of plasma testosterone in the
>   aggressive group** as compared with the nonaggressive group or with the
>   other two groups combined. **The socially dominant group also had a
>   significantly higher level of testosterone** than the nonaggressive
>   group."
>   http://journals.lww.com/psychosomaticmedicine/Abstract/1974/11000/Plasma_Testosterone__Correlation_with_Aggressive.2.aspx

-

> "Analysis of archival data from 4,462 U.S. military veterans supported
>   the first hypothesis: **Testosterone was correlated with a variety of
>   antisocial behaviors** among all individuals."
>   http://pss.sagepub.com/content/1/3/209.short

-

> "Plasma testosterone levels did not differ in fighting and nonfighting
>   individuals. Although there were significant correlations between
>   psychologic tests, the test scales did not correlate either with
>   plasma testosterone or with fighting behavior. The 10 prisoners with
>   histories of more violent and aggressive crimes in adolescence had a
>   significantly higher level of testosterone than the 11 prisoners
>   without such a history. An hypothesis is presented that **within a
>   population that is predisposed by virtue of social factors to develop
>   antisocial behaviors, levels of testosterone may be an important
>   additional factor in placing individuals at risk to commit more
>   aggressive crimes in adolescence**."
>   http://journals.lww.com/psychosomaticmedicine/Abstract/1972/07000/Assessment_of_Aggressive_Behavior_and_Plasma.6.aspx

-

> "Statistically **significant changes in MMPI–2 scale scores were found
>   at 3-month follow-up after initiating testosterone treatment relative
>   to baseline for transgender men** compared with female controls (female
>   template): reductions in Hypochondria (p < .05), Depression (p < .05),
>   Hysteria (p < .05), and Paranoia (p < .01); and increases in
>   Masculinity–Femininity scores (p < .01)."
>   http://psycnet.apa.org/psycinfo/2014-32641-001/

-

> Baron-Cohen and his colleagues recently found that **giving testosterone
>   to women decreases their ability to empathize**, particularly among
>   women whose bodies show evidence that they were exposed to higher
>   levels of testosterone in utero. And **previous research has linked high
>   levels of testosterone in the womb to autistic traits**. (Interestingly,
>   in-utero exposure to testosterone can be estimated by looking at the
>   ratio between the length of the ring finger and index finger.)
>   http://healthland.time.com/2011/05/18/study-why-some-transgendered-people-have-higher-levels-of-autistic-traits/

  -

Contrary to what many believe:

> No direct associations were found between testosterone and solitary or
>   dyadic sexual desire.
>   http://www.eje-online.org/content/165/2/331.full.pdf

**Some transgender people say they have changes parts of their personality, but I've found no studies to prove this.**

> "Chris Edwards, a trans advertising executive, says that
>   **post-transition, he was given greater levels of responsibility**—but he
>   thinks it’s because the testosterone he took changed his behavior. **He
>   became less timid and more outspoken—and was seen, at work, as more of
>   a leader**. Indeed, *some suggest that transmen might experience these
>   workplace benefits partly because, post-transition, they are happier
>   and more comfortable, and that this confidence leads to greater
>   workplace success. But if that’s the case, one would expect that
>   transwomen, armed with this same newfound confidence, would see
>   benefits. The opposite seems to be true*. "
>   http://www.newrepublic.com/article/119239/transgender-people-can-explain-why-women-dont-advance-work

-

> "Now that we’re roughly **two years into the process there has been a
>   dramatic change in personality**. This was expected, I knew there would
>   be highs and lows because the process takes a huge toll. However now
>   she just treats everyone like garbage. The whole world absolutely has
>   to revolve around her. No one can be right unless it happens to be
>   from her prospective. She exemplifies all of the negative stereotypes
>   of both transgender people and women. **The personality change went from
>   laid back punk rocker to being what I can only sum up as a stuck up
>   diva**."
>   https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100430043917AAYcyD8

Note that stories like the one above may have several possible causes, including identity changes (suddenly seeing oneself as a different gender), depression (generally bad mood) or placebo.

Comment: This is an awfully copypasta-ish answer; a little summary text at the beginning would go a long way towards resolving that.

Answer (score 2):

This is an illness, not a behavior, but [schizophrenia](http://theconversation.com/scientists-unpack-testosterones-role-in-schizophrenia-13729) is known to be correlated with high testosterone levels.  Of course, as the article I linked to itself states:

> “However, as with most endocrine and mental illnesses, schizophrenia is multifaceted (genetic, environmental etc.)...”

Of course this is just one example, but I always thought the schizophrenia-testosterone link was interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you asked for but the guy in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4YH1Eh6aALE) will tell about the study conducted on how **behaviour can affect the testosterone production**. He'll say that by doing the *power pose* (acting like you're the boss) for *2 mins will increase the testosterone by 20%* and *reduce cortisol levels*